# MySQL throwing warning for SET user variables within expressions

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that is no longer working in MySQL 8.0.17 due to the exit handler catching the warning and exiting the block. I'm guessing the error is being thrown due to the @transql variable, but i'm not 100% sure. The main issue with this is that the stored proc that is being called never reaches it because of the exit.

```
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @p1   | @p2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| HY000 | Setting user variables within expressions is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Consider alternatives: 'SET variable=expression, ...', or 'SELECT expression(s) INTO variables(s)'. |
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I checked a few other questions, but couldn't translate them into this query.

```
BEGIN
 DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, sqlwarning
    BEGIN
   GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @p1 = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, @p2 = MESSAGE_TEXT;
   ROLLBACK;
   END;

  START TRANSACTION;
  SET @key1 = key1;
    SET @transkey = transkey;
    SET @transql = CONCAT('SELECT @cckey:=cckey FROM `', key1,
    '_kr` AS t1 WHERE `transkey` = ?');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @transql;
    EXECUTE stmt
    USING @transkey;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    CALL sp_procedure1(key1, @cckey, @transkey)

  COMMIT;
END
```

Comment: `SELECT @transql;` you are selecting over `select`. Just remove the `SELECT` and it will work.

Comment: Sorry, that was me trying to debug the statement by seeing what it created. I have edited the stored proc to reflect the actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning

> Setting user variables within expressions is deprecated and will be
>   removed in a future release. Consider alternatives: 'SET
>   variable=expression, ...', or 'SELECT expression(s) INTO
>   variables(s)'.

is almost a perfect answer to your question. But to give you a hand.. The first suggestion is not applicable for prepared statements, so you need to use the second one:

```
SET @transql = CONCAT('SELECT cckey INTO @cckey FROM `', key1,
    '_kr` AS t1 WHERE `transkey` = ?');
```

See: [SELECT ... INTO Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html)

Answer (score 2):

This is a warning, not an error message, but your error handler exits on warnings as well.

The warning mesage is quite clear: you should use local variables and not user (session) variables within a compound mysql statement block.

User variables are indicated by `@` prefix (`@variablename`), while local variables do not have a prefix, but must be declared (`declare variablename type`) before using them. The declarations must preceed any other statement.