# Is there a way to alias a table or database in more than one query

Tags: mysql

I need to write a sequence of queries where I want to sometimes use a different table or database and don't want to keep writing them over and over again which can lead to a mistake.

```
SET @NAME = "Fred";
SELECT pid FROM old_table.people WHERE name = @NAME INTO @PID;
INSERT new_table.address SELECT * 
   FROM old_table.address o WHERE o.pid = @PID;
...
```

Is there a way todo a global SET or ALIAS so I don't have to repeat the database.table names again and again with the chance of a typo.

**ie looking for something like this - this is not real sql**

```
ALIAS old_table.people  @OP;
ALIAS new_table.people  @NP;
ALIAS old_table.address @OA;
ALIAS new_table.address @NA;

SET @NAME = "Fred";
SELECT pid FROM @OP WHERE name = @NAME INTO @PID;
INSERT @NA SELECT * FROM @OA o WHERE o.pid = @PID;
```

Comment: You think there is less chance of typos on aliases -  I bet not..And no there isn't a way to do as you suggest. Also what does @PID:pid do?

Comment: @PID:pid sets the var to the field pid. It is standard mysql.

Comment: The ALIAS command was an example of what I want. Sorry I was not clear. I will edit the question.

Comment: "@PID:pid sets the var to the field pid. It is standard mysql"  Which version?  It does give a syntax error on MySQL 8.0.29

Comment: sorry typo  it should be @PID:=pid I will correct it.

Comment: see: [Setting user variables within expressions is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58147748/724039)

Comment: I haven't found anything saying @PID:=pid is deprecated but I am happy to change it to a post INTO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing to what you ask for is a [VIEW](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/views.html). But I don't see how this would help avoid typos. You'd just be swapping one name for another name. You could make a typo on the view name just as easily.

You definitely cannot use a user-defined variable as a table identifier. When you use a variable in a query, it is as if you used a string value.

Comment: Thanks. I after my post thought of possibly using views, but I am not sure if they are lock to a database so that kind of defeats my objective, also my example is simplified there are many lines using the tables and I want to simple change the table/database at the top and reuse the script. The only other solution is to use a real script language which I was hoping not to have to use.

Comment: From its earliest days, SQL was intended to be used as a complement to a client programming language.