# Adding CASE function to this existing query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been trying to **add a CASE function** without success. [MySQL 8.0]

```
SELECT *
       , LEAD(total_weight, 1) OVER(
           ORDER BY weight_date DESC
       ) AS prev_total_weight
       , MIN(total_weight) OVER() AS lowest_weight
       , MAX(total_weight) OVER() AS highest_weight
       , FROM_UNIXTIME(weight_date, '%u') AS weight_week


       ,CASE
         WHEN total_weight > prev_total_weight THEN 'greater'
         WHEN total_weight = prev_total_weight THEN 'equal'
         ELSE 'less'
         END AS comparison
         

       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
          ORDER BY weight_date DESC
       ) AS RowNum
       
FROM   (
          SELECT *, weight_start_week + weight_end_week AS total_weight
          FROM   YourTable
       ) t
      
ORDER BY RowNum
```

I get the response "Unknown column 'prev_total_weight' in 'field list'"
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7683dd91c0603aa841ceea82e4e848fc

Would appreciate some help. Thanks

Comment: You cannot use aliases in expressions...  (with some exceptions, but they do not apply to this situation, see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

window function values, can not be access during processing time, the value is always 0, what ,akes them annoying.

You must first process all data . like on my new query in a CTE
and make after that your `CASE WHEN`

> ```
> CREATE TABLE YourTable
>     (`_ID` int, `weight_date` bigint, `weight_start_week` decimal(10,2), `weight_end_week` decimal(10,2))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO YourTable
>     (`_ID`, `weight_date`, `weight_start_week`, `weight_end_week`)
> VALUES
>     (52, 1636675200, 4.30, 4.30),
>     (53, 1637280000, 4.60, 7.10),
>     (54, 1637884800, 4.55, 4.05),
>     (55, 1638489600, 4.90, 4.60),
>     (56, 1639094400, 3.20, 8.25),
>     (57, 1639699200, 4.75, 7.80),
>     (58, 1640131200, 4.50, 4.70),
>     (59, 1640908800, 6.05, 5.75),
>     (60, 1641513600, 6.30, 6.60),
>     (61, 1642118400, 8.70, 7.00),
>     (62, 1642723200, 3.50, 3.60),
>     (63, 1643328000, 8.20, 3.85)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(weight_date)
>        , t.*
>        , t.weight_start_week + t.weight_end_week AS Total
> FROM   YourTable t
> ORDER BY weight_date DESC
> ```
>
> ```
> FROM_UNIXTIME(weight_date) | _ID | weight_date | weight_start_week | weight_end_week | Total
> :------------------------- | --: | ----------: | ----------------: | --------------: | ----:
> 2022-01-28 00:00:00        |  63 |  1643328000 |              8.20 |            3.85 | 12.05
> 2022-01-21 00:00:00        |  62 |  1642723200 |              3.50 |            3.60 |  7.10
> 2022-01-14 00:00:00        |  61 |  1642118400 |              8.70 |            7.00 | 15.70
> 2022-01-07 00:00:00        |  60 |  1641513600 |              6.30 |            6.60 | 12.90
> 2021-12-31 00:00:00        |  59 |  1640908800 |              6.05 |            5.75 | 11.80
> 2021-12-22 00:00:00        |  58 |  1640131200 |              4.50 |            4.70 |  9.20
> 2021-12-17 00:00:00        |  57 |  1639699200 |              4.75 |            7.80 | 12.55
> 2021-12-10 00:00:00        |  56 |  1639094400 |              3.20 |            8.25 | 11.45
> 2021-12-03 00:00:00        |  55 |  1638489600 |              4.90 |            4.60 |  9.50
> 2021-11-26 00:00:00        |  54 |  1637884800 |              4.55 |            4.05 |  8.60
> 2021-11-19 00:00:00        |  53 |  1637280000 |              4.60 |            7.10 | 11.70
> 2021-11-12 00:00:00        |  52 |  1636675200 |              4.30 |            4.30 |  8.60
> ```

> ```
> WITH CTE as  (  SELECT 
>     *
>     ,
>             LEAD(total_weight, 1) OVER(
>                ORDER BY weight_date DESC
>            ) AS prev_total_weight
>            , MIN(total_weight) OVER() AS lowest_weight
>            , MAX(total_weight) OVER() AS highest_weight
>            , FROM_UNIXTIME(weight_date, '%u') AS weight_week
>            
>              
>            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
>               ORDER BY weight_date DESC
>            ) AS RowNum
>            
>     FROM   (
>               SELECT *, weight_start_week + weight_end_week AS total_weight
>               FROM   YourTable
>            ) t
>           
> )
> SELECT
>     `_ID`, `weight_date`, `weight_start_week`, `weight_end_week`
>     prev_total_weight
>     ,lowest_weight
>     ,highest_weight
>     ,weight_week
>     ,CASE
>              WHEN total_weight > prev_total_weight THEN 'greater'
>              WHEN total_weight = prev_total_weight THEN 'equal'
>              ELSE 'less'
>              END AS comparison
>    ,RowNum
> FROM CTE
> ```

> ```
> _ID | weight_date | weight_start_week | prev_total_weight | lowest_weight | highest_weight | weight_week | comparison | RowNum
> --: | ----------: | ----------------: | ----------------: | ------------: | -------------: | :---------- | :--------- | -----:
>  63 |  1643328000 |              8.20 |              3.85 |          7.10 |          15.70 | 04          | greater    |      1
>  62 |  1642723200 |              3.50 |              3.60 |          7.10 |          15.70 | 03          | less       |      2
>  61 |  1642118400 |              8.70 |              7.00 |          7.10 |          15.70 | 02          | greater    |      3
>  60 |  1641513600 |              6.30 |              6.60 |          7.10 |          15.70 | 01          | greater    |      4
>  59 |  1640908800 |              6.05 |              5.75 |          7.10 |          15.70 | 52          | greater    |      5
>  58 |  1640131200 |              4.50 |              4.70 |          7.10 |          15.70 | 51          | less       |      6
>  57 |  1639699200 |              4.75 |              7.80 |          7.10 |          15.70 | 50          | greater    |      7
>  56 |  1639094400 |              3.20 |              8.25 |          7.10 |          15.70 | 49          | greater    |      8
>  55 |  1638489600 |              4.90 |              4.60 |          7.10 |          15.70 | 48          | greater    |      9
>  54 |  1637884800 |              4.55 |              4.05 |          7.10 |          15.70 | 47          | less       |     10
>  53 |  1637280000 |              4.60 |              7.10 |          7.10 |          15.70 | 46          | greater    |     11
>  52 |  1636675200 |              4.30 |              4.30 |          7.10 |          15.70 | 45          | less       |     12
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=990693988b41e9f6d0f57a6d8761c88f)*

Comment: This produces the following warnings: [MySQL throwing warning for SET user variables within expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58147535/mysql-throwing-warning-for-set-user-variables-within-expressions)

Comment: @Luuk no on my windows mysql server it doesn't produce an error or warning

Comment: wow, you must have a special version...  For the warning see: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=52bbeb5046be8b3f4cdff2c0a5cfcce9

Comment: no the message disappeared with the last updates

Comment: i will update to 8.0.29, and check 

Comment: Thanks for all the answers and to bnk for the solution. :)

Comment: @nbk; Warning is still present in 8.0.29.

Comment: @Luuk i added a screenshot of the query mysql workbench 8.029 server 8.0,29.  the message is stupid, as mysql can't provide a similar functionality. Instead it will use much more space with subqueriews or ctes

Comment: Just noticed that the code generates Greater even when I change the values so it should result with Less.

Comment: @bollob the vkues are during processing always 0. so i changed my answer

Comment: @nbk Thanks, works great. And I just figured out how to add  total_weight,weight_end_week. #smallstepslearning ;)

Comment: @nbk: The final query is much easier to read, when not using those assignments to variables (as in your first answer).  Thanks for editing into a version without those warnings, (Because this query will also work when they change the warning to an error.)