# How to make PHP handeling my "WITH CTE as" SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sublimetext

I added my SQL query into the PHP code, but it choose to echo "**0 results**".
I notice in Sublime Text editor that all the sql code shows in same color (not right), but when I remove the first words "**WITH CTE as (**" it becomes multi-color in Sublime Text - but the functions fails.
**In short, how do I make PHP handle my SQL?** Thanks.

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


$sql = " 
    WITH CTE as  (  SELECT *
       , LEAD(total_weight, 1) OVER(
           ORDER BY weight_date DESC
       ) AS prev_total_weight
       
       , MIN(total_weight) OVER() AS lowest_weight
       , MAX(total_weight) OVER() AS highest_weight
       , FROM_UNIXTIME(weight_date, '%u') AS weight_week
           
             
           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
              ORDER BY weight_date DESC
           ) AS RowNum
           

   FROM   (
              SELECT *, weight_start_week + weight_end_week AS total_weight
              FROM YourTable
           ) t
        
          
)
SELECT
    `_ID`, `weight_date`, `weight_start_week`, `weight_end_week`
     weight_end_week 
    ,total_weight
    ,prev_total_weight
    ,lowest_weight
    ,highest_weight
    ,weight_week
    
    
    ,CASE
             WHEN total_weight > prev_total_weight THEN 'greater'
             WHEN total_weight = prev_total_weight THEN 'equal'
             ELSE 'less'
             END AS comparison
   ,RowNum
FROM CTE

";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {


  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<table><tbody><tr><td>Latest:</td><td>" . $row["total_weight"]. "</td><td>Percent</td><td>up/down</td></td></tr><tr><td>Lowest:</td><td>" . $row["lowest_weight"].  "</td><td>" . $row["weight_week"]. "</td><td>Date:</td></tr><tr><td>Most:</td><td>" . $row["highest_weight"]. "</td><td>"  . $row["weight_week"]. "</td><td>Date:</td></tr></tbody></table>";

  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: I just copied this PHP code to Visual Studio Code, and it works. (Same result as in this [quertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72153820/adding-case-function-to-this-existing-query)).  So you might just have a problem with Sublime Text, and not with PHP or MySQL. which might need a change of then tags to `sublimetext` ?

Comment: "SQL is highlighted in strings only if those begin with certain keywords/phrases which are known to start a query" (see: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/broken-sql-syntax-highlighting-in-php-files-sublime-text-4121/61704), and `WITH` does not seem to be one of those keywords...

Comment: I created a bug for this: https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/issues/3375

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may inline the CTE into the main query, and use it as a subquery:

```sql
SELECT `_ID`, `weight_date`, `weight_start_week`, `weight_end_week`
       total_weight, prev_total_weight, lowest_weight, highest_weight,
       weight_week,
       CASE ...
FROM
(
    -- place CTE definition here
    SELECT *, ...
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY weight_date DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM ...
) t;
```

Comment: I believe you are correct, but I'm struggling to rewrite the code correctly so I can't make it work. I will keep trying, but I would be superhappy if you helped me. ;-)

Comment: Please elaborate on what is not clear.  I show your original outer query, hitting a subquery aliased as `t`, which contains the body of your CTE definition.  All you need to do is cut and paste the CTE into the `(...) t` and it should work from PHP.

Comment: I have to admit that I don't understand how much the CTE includes is since I'm new and haven't made the code. I try to edit try the SQL in Fiddle which respond I get SyntaxError. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=825a4d7be89f12ca664086326472958f